# grep how to exclude sub directory

Tags: grep

I use grep to find a string and I want to exclude one directory with `grep -rl --exclude-dir=application/res  --colour 'super'`, but it also show match under directory `application/res/`.

While when I use `grep -rl --exclude-dir=application  --colour 'super'`, nothing matched under `application` path.

How can I to exclude one sub directory when use grep.

**grep version:**

```
$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
```

**grep help:**

```
  -r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse
  -R, --dereference-recursive
                            likewise, but follow all symlinks
      --include=FILE_PATTERN
                            search only files that match FILE_PATTERN
      --exclude=FILE_PATTERN
                            skip files and directories matching FILE_PATTERN
      --exclude-from=FILE   skip files matching any file pattern from FILE
      --exclude-dir=PATTERN directories that match PATTERN will be skipped.
```

Comment: as per [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#File-and-Directory-Selection) it will only match basename, so any `/` is useless as far as I can understand... `When searching recursively, skip any subdirectory whose base name matches glob. Ignore any redundant trailing slashes in glob.`

Comment: if you are okay with another application, you can use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)... for ex: `rg -g='!application/res/' <rest-of-the-command>`

Comment: or, use `find -type f -not -path './application/res/*' -exec grep -l 'super' {} +`

Comment: @Sundeep that still processes files/dirs under ./application/res but just doesn't pass anything to grep, i.e: it's uneffective use of find

Comment: @oguzismail I don't know if that's the case, but what's the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using find you can exclude a whole path with slashes in it:

```
find . -path ./application/res -prune -o -type f -exec grep -l super {} +
```

Despite being more portable, this will be slower than `grep -r`. But as far as I'm concerned, GNU grep doesn't provide a mechanism for excluding paths.